# Url rewriting and Proxying in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

I'm using nginx to proxy a request to an URL contained in the query string.

Basically my idea is proxying this request:

```
/proxy?url=http://google.com
```

to

```
http://google.com
```

How can I accomplish this?

I tried with

```
location /proxy\?url=(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$1;    
}
```

but it doees not work. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The query string is not part of the normalized URI used by the `location` and `rewrite` directives. However, all of the arguments are available as `$arg_` variables.

For example:

```
location /proxy {
    proxy_pass http://$arg_url;    
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Using redirect works as expected but that's not my case.